# Use cases for TLS inside AWS VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, tls1.2, amazon-vpc, vpc

I just watched a presentation from AWS about ElastiCache and they mention that if you want to strengthen security you can use TLS for data in transit.

I really can't see the benefits of that considering we also lose a good percentage of performance.
Anyone aware of any use-cases for TLS inside AWS VPC?

One of my thoughts was that a compromised instance inside the same VPC can sniff traffic, but that is apparently not possible: https://aws.amazon.com/answers/networking/vpc-security-capabilities/#Packet_Sniffing

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's common in security situations where you are dealing with highly sensitive data, you would certainly consider both encryption of data in transit and at rest.

It mainly depends on the security policy of the application runs under. The security policy would be established by management and intransit encryption can be mandatory in HIPAA or PCI applications.

Possible attack vectors are "man-in-the middle" or unauthorized access by internal users.

I'm not sure what the performance hit would be, but I don't think it would be significant.

Also note this from the article you reference:

> While Amazon EC2 does provide ample data protection between customers by default, as a standard practice it is best to **always encrypt sensitive traffic**.

Comment: HIPAA, not HIPPA (I tried editing your post to fix it but stack overflow doesn't allow people to fix typos, as it has a minimum number of characters it requires you change).

Comment: Thanks @RodrigoM, but where would that man-in-the-middle be sitting? 
As for unauthorised access, if you have root access to the machine running your client app, there are many things you can do even if you have encrypted traffic. Or maybe you have something else in mind?
The performance hit for Redis I measured to be around 30-40%.
The citation probably means "you should protect yourself just in case we screw something up", and of course that's a valid one :)

Comment: Some on premise setup would provide a lot of attack exposure to MTM. DNS cache poisoning

Comment: I agree with you, but I think you're talking about something outside of the AWS VPC world?

Comment: The question is about a AWS VPC network that say doesn't have any connections outside to the real world

Comment: Some on premise setup would provide a lot of attack exposure to MTM. DNS cache poisoning. Re root access you have a lot of problems if someone has gained root access. But you still have to encrypt sensitive data.

Comment: Your question is about AWS. There are a lot of hybrid Cloud services in AWS eg Direct Connect, VPN, Snowball. This security question would impact these AWS customer implementations as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208527/discussion-between-nikolay-dimitrov-and-rodrigo-m).

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should have [Zero Trust](https://doubleoctopus.com/security-wiki/network-architecture/zero-trust/) of anything in your network.